# Can be deleted - Identifying what causes the boot process to hang on 'A start job is running for apparmor initalization'

Tags: boot, apparmor

I am using a laptop with dual boot (Ubuntu 18.04.3LTS and WIN). It has has an i3-5010U chip with Intel HD5500 graphics.

Since I use Ubuntu both for normal desktop use and for audio (Cadence, Catia, Carla, Calf), I start my system via GRUB on either the 5.0.0-31 generic kernel or the 4.15.0-65 lowlatency.
As an audio interface I use a USB-sound card (Scarlett Focusrite).

This used to work like a charm. And switching between Ubuntu and Windows or between generic and lowlatency didn't give me any trouble.

Then, from one day to another, I ran into booting issues. More precisely: when I boot the low latency kernel, the boot hangs for ~8 min. on `A start job is running for apparmor initalization`.

part of my `boot.log` :

[image: part of my boot.log]

When the desktop finally appears, the system has not been able to initialize apparmor.

```
systemctl status apparmor.service
```

[image: returns this]

And running `sudo apparmor_status` returns:

```
apparmor module is loaded.
39 profiles are loaded.
37 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient
   /snap/core/7917/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/core/7917/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/bin/evince
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer
   /usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
   /usr/sbin/cupsd
   /usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party
   /usr/sbin/ippusbxd
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
   libreoffice-senddoc
   libreoffice-soffice//gpg
   libreoffice-xpdfimport
   man_filter
   man_groff
   snap-update-ns.core
   snap-update-ns.gmail-desktop
   snap-update-ns.gnome-calculator
   snap-update-ns.gnome-characters
   snap-update-ns.gnome-logs
   snap-update-ns.gnome-system-monitor
   snap.core.hook.configure
   snap.gmail-desktop.gmail-desktop
   snap.gnome-calculator.gnome-calculator
   snap.gnome-characters.gnome-characters
   snap.gnome-logs.gnome-logs
   snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor
2 profiles are in complain mode.
   libreoffice-oopslash
   libreoffice-soffice
2 processes have profiles defined.
2 processes are in enforce mode.
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed (960) 
   /usr/sbin/cupsd (951) 
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

I then played around with booting both kernels with apparmor enabled and disabled and found out:

1. As long as I boot the generic kernel exclusively, I can have apparmor enabled without problems.
2. The problems start as soon as I boot lowlatency with apparmor enabled.
3. If I disable apparmor before booting lowlatency, the boot won't hang.
4. If I boot lowlatency with apparmor enabled, the boot will hang not only on the lowlatency, but on the directly following next generic boot as well. This is the apparmor status after the next generic boot :

   [image: screenshot]

   Only after re-booting the generic kernel one more time, the booting and apparmor is back to normal.

   I compared outputs of

   ```
   sudo apparmor_status
   ```

   after

   - the faulty lowlatency boot
   - the following generic boot (also faulty)
   - the generic reboot (normal again)

   without manually disabling apparmor at any point.

   All three status reports are exactly the same, except for the numbers following `cups-browsed` and `cupsd`. Here's an example:

   ```
   [...]
   2 processes are in enforce mode.
      /usr/sbin/cups-browsed (960) 
      /usr/sbin/cupsd (951) 
   [...]
   ```

---

Update:

5. When I reboot lowlatency after a faulty first lowlatency-boot, it's all OK again. Normal boot with apparmor initialized. Only thing I noticed is a slightly different output of `sudo apparmor_service`, which has now 3 processes with defined profiles and 3 in enforce mode, where all others so far had 2 and 2:

   ```
   3 processes have profiles defined.
   3 processes are in enforce mode.
      /sbin/dhclient (1432) 
      /usr/sbin/cups-browsed (937) 
      /usr/sbin/cupsd (867)
   ```
6. When I boot the generic kernel version after last step (the successful reboot of preceding faulty lowlatency boot), the boot process is hanging again and apparmor fails to initialize. Here's the status reports:

   [image: apparmor.service]

   [image: apparmor_service]

   So, under the bottom line: the booting hangs everytime I switch to the other kernel version. But from the first re-boot of the same kernel on, all is OK again. Until I switch back to the other kernel (and independent of having left a properly booted kernel or a faulty one).

   If I disable `apparmor`, I can load any kernel at normal speed.

   This is my apparmor shell script in `/etc/init.d`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   #    Copyright (c) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007
   #     NOVELL (All rights reserved)
   #    Copyright (c) 2008, 2009 Canonical, Ltd.
   #
   #    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   #    modify it under the terms of version 2 of the GNU General Public
   #    License published by the Free Software Foundation.
   #
   #    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   #    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   #    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   #    GNU General Public License for more details.
   #
   #    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
   #    along with this program; if not, contact Novell, Inc.
   # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   # Authors:
   #  Steve Beattie <steve.beattie@canonical.com>
   #  Kees Cook <kees@ubuntu.com>
   #
   # /etc/init.d/apparmor
   #
   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides: apparmor
   # Required-Start: $local_fs
   # Required-Stop: umountfs
   # Default-Start: S
   # Default-Stop:
   # Short-Description: AppArmor initialization
   # Description: AppArmor init script. This script loads all AppArmor profiles.
   ### END INIT INFO

   . /lib/apparmor/functions
   . /lib/lsb/init-functions

   usage() {
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status|recache}"
   }

   test -x ${PARSER} || exit 0 # by debian policy
   # LSM is built-in, so it is either there or not enabled for this boot
   test -d /sys/module/apparmor || exit 0

   securityfs() {
       # Need securityfs for any mode
       if [ ! -d "${AA_SFS}" ]; then
           if cut -d" " -f2,3 /proc/mounts | grep -q "^${SECURITYFS} securityfs"'$' ; then
               log_action_msg "AppArmor not available as kernel LSM."
               log_end_msg 1
               exit 1
           else
               log_action_begin_msg "Mounting securityfs on ${SECURITYFS}"
               if ! mount -t securityfs none "${SECURITYFS}"; then
                   log_action_end_msg 1
                   log_end_msg 1
                   exit 1
               fi
           fi
       fi
       if [ ! -w "$AA_SFS"/.load ]; then
           log_action_msg "Insufficient privileges to change profiles."
           log_end_msg 1
           exit 1
       fi
   }

   # Allow "recache" even when running on the liveCD
   if [ "$1" = "recache" ]; then
       log_daemon_msg "Recaching AppArmor profiles"
       recache_profiles
       rc=$?
       log_end_msg "$rc"
       exit $rc
   fi

   # do not perform start/stop/reload actions when running from liveCD
   test -d /rofs/etc/apparmor.d && exit 0

   rc=255
   case "$1" in
       start)
           if [ -x /usr/bin/systemd-detect-virt ] && \
              systemd-detect-virt --quiet --container && \
              ! is_container_with_internal_policy; then
               log_daemon_msg "Not starting AppArmor in container"
               log_end_msg 0
               exit 0
           fi
           log_daemon_msg "Starting AppArmor profiles"
           securityfs
           load_configured_profiles
           rc=$?
           log_end_msg "$rc"
           ;;
       stop)
           log_daemon_msg "Clearing AppArmor profiles cache"
           clear_cache
           rc=$?
           log_end_msg "$rc"
           cat >&2 <<EOM
   All profile caches have been cleared, but no profiles have been unloaded.
   Unloading profiles will leave already running processes permanently
   unconfined, which can lead to unexpected situations.

   To set a process to complain mode, use the command line tool
   'aa-complain'. To really tear down all profiles, run the init script
   with the 'teardown' option."
   EOM
           ;;
       teardown)
           if [ -x /usr/bin/systemd-detect-virt ] && \
              systemd-detect-virt --quiet --container && \
              ! is_container_with_internal_policy; then
               log_daemon_msg "Not tearing down AppArmor in container"
               log_end_msg 0
               exit 0
           fi
           log_daemon_msg "Unloading AppArmor profiles"
           securityfs
           running_profile_names | while read profile; do
               if ! unload_profile "$profile" ; then
                   log_end_msg 1
                   exit 1
               fi
           done
           rc=0
           log_end_msg $rc
           ;;
       restart|reload|force-reload)
           if [ -x /usr/bin/systemd-detect-virt ] && \
              systemd-detect-virt --quiet --container && \
              ! is_container_with_internal_policy; then
               log_daemon_msg "Not reloading AppArmor in container"
               log_end_msg 0
               exit 0
           fi
           log_daemon_msg "Reloading AppArmor profiles"
           securityfs
           clear_cache
           load_configured_profiles
           rc=$?

           log_end_msg "$rc"
           ;;
       status)
           securityfs
           if [ -x /usr/sbin/aa-status ]; then
               aa-status --verbose
           else
               cat "$AA_SFS"/profiles
           fi
           rc=$?
           ;;
       *)
           usage
           rc=1
           ;;
       esac
   exit $rc
   ```

Does someone have an idea what I could do to identify what causes my boot process to hang on an `apparmor start-job`?

I'm fairly new to Linux and any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us `systemctl status apparmor.service` with enabled apparmor.service. Edit your question for output.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I added a screenshot.

Comment: with lowlatency kernel boot please if possible.

Comment: I booted the low latency kernel with apparmor enabled. I edited my question again to include the results and further info.

Comment: strange `sudo apparmor_status` with lowlatency kernel. do realy need him?

Comment: If you're asking whether I need apparmor when using the lowlatency kernel: I'm not entirely sure what apparmor does. But I thought online security is part of it. Of course I could live with not being online while on lowlatency. But this enabling and disabling of apparmor is a bit time consuming. Or could I make an entry in one of the scripts so that apparmor is loaded on generic boot and disabled on lowlatency boot?

Comment: I just noticed that 'sudo apparmor_status' gives another result. Will check that as well on lowlatency and return with that...

Comment: I rephrased my question to give it a better structure. I also included the output of 'sudo apparmor_status'.